# Target container is not a DOM element - error in importing a function

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I'm a newbie here so apologies for what might be a very elemental question.

I am trying to fiddle with different ways to import components in React by following a tutorial but I can't seem to make it work.  There must be a simple tweak that I am sorely missing.

I am trying to create export a component (Person2) to another JS (App)

Person2.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

function Person2(){
 return (
   <div>
   <h1>Millie</h1>
   <p>PERSON 2</p>
   </div>
 );
}


/*
ReactDOM.render(
   <div>
       <h1>Hello World!</h1>
   </div>,
   document.getElementById('#p2')
);
*/


//ReactDOM.render(<Person2 />, document.getElementById('App'));
ReactDOM.render(<Person2 />, document.querySelector('#p2'));
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './css/App.css';
import './css/w3.css'
import Person from './Person'; // Import a component from another file using class with default export
import './Person2'; // Import a a component from another file using ReactDom.render


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <header className="App-header">
        <p>this is the header</p>
      </header>
      <body>
        <div class="w3-row">
          <Person name="Max" age="28"/>
          <Person name="Ann" age="18"/>
          <div id = "p2"></div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any idea where I went wrong?

I'm getting an error "Error: Target container is not a DOM element."

Comment: What file is the entry point? Share the code

Comment: Here is the full (not working) code https://github.com/rosanna-ang/udemymax/

Answer (score 0):

ReactDOM.render is usually used only for rendering your root component, I don't think you should use it in that case. With that said, the problem is the order the code is executed. You try to render your `Person2` component in a node that hasn't been yet rendered, thus you get that error

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very strange use case, you should be using `export` not `ReactDOM.render` for this example.

In `Person2`, change to this:

```js
//ReactDOM.render(<Person2 />, document.querySelector('#p2'));
export default Person2;
```

Then to use it, in `App` change to this:

```js
import Person2 from './Person2'; // for default export

...

<Person name="Ann" age="18"/>
//<div id = "p2"></div> *** remove this ***
<Person2 /> // Use like this
```

If for whatever reason your app requires the use of `ReactDOM.render` here, I'd add a check for safety to make sure the element exists first.

```js
if (!!document.getElementById('p2')) {
  ReactDOM.render(<Person2/>, document.getElementById('p2'));
}
```